# sort 2 array's with objects of coordinates to get a list of which are closest to each-other

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I have 2 array's with objects of coordinates. For example:

```
  const coordinates = [
    { x: 2, y: 6 },
    { x: 14, y: 10 },
    { x: 7, y: 10 },
    { x: 11, y: 6 },
  ];
  const coordinates2 = [
    { x: 8, y: 9 },
    { x: 25, y: 11 },
    { x: 2, y: 11 },
    { x: 7, y: 8 },
  ];
```

I want to make an sort function which will return which are closest to each other.

I tried multiple things but can not figure it out.
Any solution is accepted. Maybe sort 1 to the other or sort both at the same time.

This is wat I want to achive:

```
result array 1[
    { x: 2, y: 6 },
    { x: 14, y: 10 },
    { x: 7, y: 10 },
    { x: 11, y: 6 },
  ];
  result array 2 = [
    { x: 2, y: 11 }, // beceause it is closest to {x: 2,y: 6}
    { x: 25, y: 11 }, // beceayse it is closest to {x: 14,y: 10},
    { x: 7, y: 8 }, // beceause it is closest to { x: 7, y: 10 }
    { x: 8, y: 9 }, // beceause it is closest to {x: 11,y: 6} after x: 7, y:10 but x:7, y:8 is even closer
  ];
```

^ the result can be different. But I want the most efficient distance between them.

The formula to see the distance of coordination a and coordination b is the following:
distance=√((x1-x2)²+(y1-y2)²).

If anyone has an idea or an tip please let me know !

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Can you provide an example of what results you are looking for from the above data?  Right now it's not clear if you want A) a point from {1} and a point from {2} that are closest, or B) every point from {1} along with each point from {2} that is closest to it, or  C) every point from {2} along with each point from {1} that is closest to it, or ... ?

Comment: Sure ! I will edit the message.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the first array by getting the closest coordinate from the second array.

```js
const
    getClosest = ({ x, y }, data) => data.reduce((a, b) => Math.hypot(x - a.x, y - a.y) < Math.hypot(x - b.x, y - b.y) ? a : b),
    coordinates = [{ x: 2, y: 6 }, { x: 14, y: 10 }, { x: 7, y: 10 }, { x: 11, y: 6 }, { x: 6, y: 2 }],
    coordinates2 = [{ x: 8, y: 9 }, { x: 25, y: 11 }, { x: 2, y: 11 }, { x: 18, y: 21 }, { x: 7, y: 8 }],
    pairs = coordinates.map(o => [o, getClosest(o, coordinates2)]);

console.log(pairs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this example ! Wil try to edit this a bit to make it work. But the problem is I do not want duplicates.

Maybe can make something like this work